# Why is Quark Mixing forbidden in the Lagrangian (pre CKM)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model

The corresponding term in Lagrangian for the coupling of quarks to gauge fields reads: $$  \sum_{i} \bar Q_i D_\mu \gamma^ \mu Q_i .$$

Considering the Yukawa terms, it is generally stated that no symmetry principle forbids generation mixing terms in the first place. Therefore one writes in general

$$\sum_{i,j} \bar Y_{ij} Q_i \Phi Q_j .$$

After symmetry breaking the mass matrices are introduced, which aren't orthogonal. Global SU(2) invariance is then used to diagonalize them and this eventually leads to generation mixing through the $W$-Bosons, expressed through the CKM matrix.

**I was wondering why generation mixing terms in the Lagrangian aren't allowed in the first place for the Quark-Gauge-Field coupling term, like it is for the Yukawa term. In other words: What prevents the Quark-Gauge part of the Lagrangian from being**

$$  \sum_{i} \bar Q_i D_{\mu,ij} \gamma^ \mu Q_j,$$

which of course would mean that some gauge coupling matrices $g_{ij}$ appear in the $D_{\mu,ij}$ term, instead of the universal $g$.

Comment: If by $D_{\mu\,,ij}$ you mean $D_{\mu\,,ij}=\delta_{ij}\partial_\mu-i g_{ij}W_\mu$, then is gauge invariance that enforces $g_{ij}=g\delta_{ij}$. It is pretty clear if you move the gauge coupling $g$ to the gauge boson kinetic term.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant by $D_{\mu\,,ij}$. The gauge boson kinetic term is $F_{\mu\nu}^a F^{\mu\nu a}= (\partial_\mu A_\nu^a - \partial_\nu A_\mu^a + g' f^{abc} A_\mu^b A_\nu^c) ( ...) $. In my understanding allowing $g=g_{ij}$ would mean allowing the possibility that the weak force couples with difference strength to the different quarks, and with another strength, denoted $g'$ above to itself. This may be ugly, but I'm unfortunately not able to see why it should be forbidden by symmetry. Any further thoughts would be awesome!

Comment: As I've already said, it is gauge invariance that forbids it. If you don't see it, just try to do a gauge transformation (say abelian) to $\bar{Q}_{j}iD_{\mu\,,ji}Q_j$ which will not result to be invariant unless $g_{ij}=g\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: @TwoBs Yep thanks, that is correct! $\sum_{i} \bar Q_i D_{\mu,ij} \gamma^ \mu Q_j$ transforms to $\sum_{i} \bar{ (U Q_i)} D'_{\mu,ij} \gamma^ \mu (UQ_j)= \sum_{i} \bar Q_i D_{\mu,ij} \gamma^ \mu Q_j - QU^\dagger ig_{ij} \gamma^\mu a_\mu(x)UQ_j + \delta_{ij} QU \gamma^\mu a_\mu U Q_j$  and therefore $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$